API Key of Google Gemini is not working on Google collab
I was create an api key, and I was following this tutorial. When I replace 'GOOGLE_API_KEY' in cell code bellow:
# Or use `os.getenv('GOOGLE_API_KEY')` to fetch an environment variable.
GOOGLE_API_KEY=userdata.get('[REDACTED]')

genai.configure(api_key=GOOGLE_API_KEY)

I got an error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SecretNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-e4a84a54faa3> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 # Or use `os.getenv('GOOGLE_API_KEY')` to fetch an environment variable.
----> 2 GOOGLE_API_KEY=userdata.get('[REDACTED]')
      3 
      4 genai.configure(api_key=GOOGLE_API_KEY)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/google/colab/userdata.py in get(key)
     51     )
     52   if not resp.get('exists', False):
---> 53     raise SecretNotFoundError(key)
     54   if not resp.get('access', False):
     55     raise NotebookAccessError(key)

SecretNotFoundError: Secret '[REDACTED]' does not exist.

I tried creating API keys in my account but it not working.

If that is your api key i suggest you create a new one your not supposed to share it.

You need to click the key on the left bar in Colab

then when you run this it should output your key
from google.colab import userdata
# The gemini api key
API_KEY = userdata.get('API_KEY')
print(API_KEY)


The key sign is not appearing on my GCP Co-Lab console , do I need to enable any API ?
